# How can I bubble up an underlying error type from a custom error type?

Tags: rust

I have a custom Error that I use to wrap around several standard Rust errors that looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    details: String,
}

impl MyError {
    fn new(msg: &str) -> MyError {
        dbg!(msg);
        MyError {
            details: msg.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.details)
    }
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for MyError {
    fn from(err: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        MyError::new(&err.to_string())
    }
}

impl From<std::string::FromUtf8Error> for MyError {
    fn from(err: std::string::FromUtf8Error) -> Self {
        MyError::new(&err.to_string())
    }
}
```

Right now, I simply bubble up the the error message into my MyError. However, I'd also like to create a method that returns what the underlying Error type was so that I can match on it with an Enum or something at a later point in time. How can I add new method to my Error that outputs the underlying error type? I see that `Error.kind()` may be what I'm looking for, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: And why won't you make `MyError` a enum over different types of errors? `enum MyError { Utf8(std::string::FromUtf8Error), Io(std::io::Error) }`

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the `Any` trait.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html
Your error type could be `Box<dyn Error + Any>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the implementation of what I mentioned in the comments, and below is how you would use it and match it: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18fb2f59609f416f4f110b509cc9cea8)

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    FromUtf8(std::string::FromUtf8Error),
    Io(std::io::Error),
    Generic(String),
}

impl MyError {
    fn new(msg: &str) -> Self {
        dbg!(msg);
        MyError::Generic(msg.to_string())
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use MyError::*;
        match self {
            FromUtf8(e) => write!(f, "{}", e),
            Io(e) => write!(f, "{}", e),
            Generic(e) => write!(f, "{}", e),
        }
    }
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for MyError {
    fn from(err: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        MyError::Io(err)
    }
}

impl From<std::string::FromUtf8Error> for MyError {
    fn from(err: std::string::FromUtf8Error) -> Self {
        MyError::FromUtf8(err)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e1 = MyError::new("Oops");
    println!("{}", e1);
    use MyError::*;
    match e1 {
        FromUtf8(e) => println!("UTF8 error"),
        Io(e) => println!("IO error"),
        Generic(e) => println!("Just an error"),
    }
}
```